# Flutter throws error when context is passed to a Provider from the init method

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a MainScreen (stateful) with the following method:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_)  async {
          loadFirebaseUser(context);
        });
  }
```

My 'loadFirebaseUser' method is in another file called Constants.dart which can be used from any screen.
The function is as follows:

```
Future<bool> loadFirebaseUser(BuildContext context) async {
  Auth _auth = Auth();
  FirebaseUser cUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  if (cUser.isEmailVerified) {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Profile')
        .document(cUser.uid)
        .get();
    if (snapshot.data != null) {
      User user = Provider.of<UserData>(context).getUser();
      user = User.fromMap(snapshot);
      Provider.of<UserData>(context).setUser(user);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

I am getting the follwing error when this code is executed:

```
Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
```

Needless to say that as result of this the user is not getting loaded. The error points to the following line:

```
User user = Provider.of<UserData>(context).getUser();
```

I want the 'loadFirebaseUSer' function to execute automatically and not on any button click, so this is the only place I know to place this code. Is there a way to achieve this differently? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to get context this way?

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      var myState = Provider.of<MyState>(context);
.......
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't  User user = Provider.of<UserData>(context).getUser() means the same as your answer (MyState = UserData)? What role does Future.Delayed plays? Please elaborate so I can learn something from it

Comment: The role is to obtain correct context inside of Future.delayed

Comment: I tried it and it does not work. I am getting the same error unfortunately